# Versioning in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, version-control, versioning

I´ve got a question about versioning in Android Studio. Is there any easy way to make different Versions of my app? Let´s say I´ve got a working app and I would like to add more stuff. Can I easily make a backup of the working app, so if I mess something up while taking changes I can easily go back to my working version?

Comment: Try out version control systems like git

Comment: Yes you can. As @dustblue mentioned it you can use solutions like Git or Mercurial. Have a look at github.com or bitbucket.org. Then you just enable it in Android Studio (menu VCS)

Comment: try version control and work on different branches

Comment: Android Studio has built in Versioning. You can configure it. It will be more convenient if you are initial at versioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git for that.

first install git.

in project

```
git init
```

in git you can create branches in which you can keep your app versions.

```
git checkout -b branchname
```

Keep your stable working code in Master branch.

when ever you work on a new feature, do that in different branch, whenever you are done, merge that with the master branch.

and whenever you need to save code, make a commit.
git commit -m "message"

you can use github, gitlab, bitbucket for this.
and then keep the code on server.

Comment: at the moment i´m using Bitbucket. But i thought with that i can only transfer my code easily to other computers or colleagues. i´ll check out how to make different branches. thank you.

Comment: if you are using android studio, you can also use gui to use git. On the bottom right corner of android studio, there is a git button. You can create branches with that. BTW People also use "tags" to save states and versions of their app.